# I've got InvalidArgumentException when i used switch_to.window by selenium / Python

Tags: python, selenium

I've seen many example script on how to use selenium switch_to.window

Here is an example script regarding what I learned, doesn't work at all:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from pprint import pprint
    
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    
    
    script="""
        myWindow = window.open("", "ChildWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    """
    browser.execute_script(script)
    
    wHandles = browser.window_handles
    pprint(wHandles)
    
    handle = wHandles[1]
    print(handle, type(handle))
    
    browser.switch_to.window(handle)
```

I've got that error message:

> InvalidArgumentException: Expected "handle" to be a string, got
> [object Undefined] undefined

Obviously i tired with normal web page with same result a as well.

Is there anyone with same problem?

Comment: Your code has multiple print statements.  What did they print out?

Comment: Only for debug :)

Comment: I'm pulling up the correct output.

Comment: It's due to Firefox 80 it's a bug.

Comment: Works on Chrome though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot about webdriver chrome/firefox - better use webdriver_manager which manages the latest browsers with your python version
More about webdriver_manager can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

here is the flawlessly code

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

script = """
        myWindow = window.open("", "ChildWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    """
browser.execute_script(script)

wHandles = browser.window_handles
print(wHandles)

handle = wHandles[1]
print(handle, type(handle))

browser.switch_to.window(handle)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Seems to be stackovwrflow use a  dumb algorithm what closed my question whilst your solution the real solution. Thank you.  I could only give up a up triangle yet. I'm trying to contact to support team.

Comment: Accept it when you can, thanks and welcome