# Selenium Python: Expected "handle" to be a string, got [object Undefined] undefined

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Firefox. I click a button but the page opens as a new tab and selenium stays focused on the original page with the button. I'm trying to switch and get the new url.

```
time.sleep(4)
second_driver.switch_to.window(second_driver.window_handles[1])
print(second_driver.current_url)
```

I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Expected "handle" to be a string, got [object Undefined] undefined
```

I also tried the following but it didn't have an effect. I still got the url of the old page.

```
second_driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

Comment: could you please try this in the second line. second_driver.switch_to.window(str(second_driver.window_handles[1]))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949719/ive-got-invalidargumentexception-when-i-used-switch-to-window-by-selenium-pyt It's a firefox bug. I'd suggest switching your excutable path to a webdriver manager.

Comment: second_driver.switch_to.window(str(second_driver.window_handles[1])) gives the same error

Comment: I would try getting the handle and then passing it... so handle = second_driver.window_handles[1] and then second_driver.switch_to.window(handle)  Also note that the order of the handles in this array is not guaranteed across drivers.

Answer (score 4):

This was a Geckodriver bug. It was resolved on the 0.27.0 version release:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

I have used to experience the same issue with the 0.24.0 version and then I have upgraded the Geckodriver to this version, and then the issue stopped happening.

However, I recommend using always the latest version of Geckodriver. I have checked with the 0.29.0 version and the bug is also gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Java Selenium 3.141.59 when using switching tab on Firefox webdriver launched by the gecko version 24.
The problem was solved just by replacing the geckodriver by a later version 0.33.0 (without any change on the implementation)